# Convert multiple isinstance checks to structural pattern matching

Tags: python, isinstance, python-3.10, structural-pattern-matching

I want to convert this existing code to use pattern matching:

```
if isinstance(x, int):
    pass
elif isinstance(x, str):
    x = int(x)
elif isinstance(x, (float, Decimal)):
    x = round(x)
else:
    raise TypeError('Unsupported type')
```

How do you write [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) checks with pattern matching, and how do you test against multiple possible types like `(float, Decimal)` at the same time?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

### Example converted to pattern matching

Here's the equivalent code using *match* and *case*:

```
match x:
    case int():
        pass
    case str():
        x = int(x)
    case float() | Decimal():
        x = round(x)
    case _:
        raise TypeError('Unsupported type')
```

### Explanation

[PEP 634](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634) specifies that [isinstance()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) checks are performed with [class patterns](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/#class-patterns).  To check for an instance of *str*, write `case str(): ...`.  Note that the parentheses are essential.  That is how the grammar determines that this is a class pattern.

To check multiple classes at a time, PEP 634 provides an [or-pattern](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/#or-patterns) using the `|` operator.  For example, to check whether an object is an instance of *float* or *Decimal*, write `case float() | Decimal(): ...`.  As before, the parentheses are essential.

Comment: Also see the [pattern matching tutorial](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/#adding-a-ui-matching-objects) for more advanced `isinstance` checks which include constraints on properties of the class.

Comment: Unfortunately this pattern is bit prone to [breaking exhaustiveness checking](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=cc8fa2867a9f2990a768ffd708782a99), i.e., when accidentally forgetting a `()` the `assert_never` suddenly loses its functionality! In this regard a traditional chain of `if instance(): ... elif isinstance(): ... else: assert_never()` is less error prone.

Comment: @bluenote10 That makes no sense.  In `case _: raise TypeError`, it is trivial to substitute `case _: assert_never()`, error logging, or anything else that you would normally use in an else-clause.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger I know. I was just trying to say that forgetting the parenthesis is dangerous, because it will create an irrefutable pattern, i.e., it will accidentally match everything, and therefore `assert_never` loses its capability of performing exhaustiveness checks. Clearly, my latter example has a bug, but there is no (obvious?) way for the type checker to identify a bug here, because it cannot guess if the broad capture was an accident. Perhaps a linter can avoid such issues, if it forbids irrefutable patterns.

Comment: @bluenote10 That is also incorrect.  1) The `case _` always matches.  2) The match-case statement raises an exception if any but the last pattern always matches.  So, if you use the final `case _` as shown, then any error leaving off parens will be detected instantly.  Please just try the example code with and without the hypothetical error.  That would have saved two comments that didn't make any sense.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger I'm referring to type-checking time, not runtime. Just click on the mypy playground link to verify. It happily type checks the "broken" example. This mistake actually did happen to me, so it is futile to argue that it is "incorrect" that one can make this mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Using python `match` `case`

**Without Exception handling**

```
match x:
    case int():
        pass
    case str():
        x = int(x)
    case float() | Decimal():
        x = round(x)
    case _:
        raise TypeError('Unsupported type')
```

**Some extras**

There are still some flows in this code.

**With exception handling**

```
match x:
    case int():
        pass
    case str():
        try:
            x = int(x)
        except ValueError:
            raise TypeError('Unsupported type')
    case float() | Decimal():
        x = round(x)
    case _:
        raise TypeError('Unsupported type')
```

**As a function**

```
def func(x):
    match x:
        case int():
            pass
        case str():
            try:
                x = int(x)
            except ValueError:
                raise TypeError('Unsupported type')
        case float() | Decimal():
            x = round(x)
        case _:
            raise TypeError('Unsupported type')
    return x
```