# Replace similar if statements using type checks to determine the order of arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code:

```
def distance(a, b):
    ta = type(a)
    tb = type(b)
    if (ta == Vector and tb == Line):
        return ObjectRelations.point_to_line_distance(a, b)
    if (ta == Line and tb == Vector):
        return ObjectRelations.point_to_line_distance(b, a)
```

Is there a way to do both `if` comparisons in one? The order of arguments given to `point_to_line_distance` matters because of how my `Vector` and `Line` objects work. I want to check if *either* `a` or `b` is a `Line` and then check whether the other one is a `Vector`.

What would the best way to do this?

My way of doing it would work, but I just want to write clean code and my solution is not ideal.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Yes, but *it won't be any simpler*. Also, please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python.

Comment: Store in a dict by type e.g. `d = { type(a):a, type(b):b }` and then simply return `ObjectRelations.point_to_line_distance(d[Vector], d[Line])`? I'm not sure it adds much, if anything, in terms of clarity or simplicity tbh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Python 3.10 or newer you can use [structural pattern matching](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/) to replace the `if` statements and explicit type checks:

```
def distance(a, b):
    match (a, b):
        case (Vector(), Line()):
            vector, line = a, b
        case (Line(), Vector()):
            line, vector = a, b
        case _:
            raise ValueError('Expected one Line and one Vector')
    return ObjectRelations.point_to_line_distance(vector, line)
```

See also: [Convert multiple isinstance checks to structural pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67524641/convert-multiple-isinstance-checks-to-structural-pattern-matching)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, proper way to check for type is by using `isinstance` - this way you also check for any potential subtypes.

Secondly, you can clean up that code by finding out which object is a Line, assigning it to designated variable, then checking if other is of a correct type and working on variables clear about their type.

```
def distance(a, b):
    if isinstance(a, Line):
        line = a
        vec = b
    elif isinstance(b, Line):
        line = b
        vec = a
    if not isinstance(vec, Vector):
        raise TypeError
    return ObjectRelations.point_to_line_distance(vec, line)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `or` to connect the two if statements. It would be

`if (ta == Vector and tb == Line) or (ta == Line and tb == Vector):`

Comment: OP requires different behaviour for each of the if statements (note the `(a, b)` and `(b ,a)`).

Comment: I was answering his question about how to combine two if statements.